# PHP if/else statement function problems

Tags: php, sql, if-statement

I've created a css3 progress bar. I want to great so if the user have example 3 likes/points it says: 14% and if it have 5 it says 29%(this was just an example).

I'm very new to if and else so i think i used it wrong. With the code under it only displays "1 like".

The code are as follow:

```
<?php

session_start();
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","facebook");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

  $username = $_SESSION['username'];




$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT likes FROM login where username='".$username."'");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))


if($row['likes'] > 0) { ?>


<div class="meter animate" align="left">
    <span style="width: 14%"><span>1 likes </span></span>
</div>

<?php
} else if($row['likes'] > 1){ ?>
<div class="meter animate" align="left">
    <span style="width: 28%"><span>2 likes </span></span>
</div>

<?php
}
mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

Comment: See my answer....in order for a percentage meter to work as intended, you need to know what 100% will be.....then use that in your calculations, no complicated if then statements, just pure division.

Comment: okei, tahnks for help! But then, how do i check i user got 1 or 2 likes and returns that in proggress bar?

Comment: is 1 and 2 the only amounts theyll ever have?? Whats the maximum they can have?  Just set the max in the code....the width is set automatically

Comment: Oh no sorry, 1 and 2 is NOT the max

Comment: so whats the problem, my question is when is 100% reached?  You need a comparison figure, cuz the way you wanna do it you'll end up with 15 if then statements, incrementally adjusting manually.  Thats lunacy.....just use math man

Comment: My example below is pretty straightforward, if you set $total to 2 and the amount of likes is 2, it will show 100%, if you set $total to 10, it will show 20% for 2 likes, if you set it to 100, it iwll show 2% for 2 likes.  Just set $total at whatever you want the MAX likes to be and youll get your width.= based on that.

Comment: Oh i understand what you ment now! 100% is reached at 10. Now i understand :) SOrry for being new mang

Comment: lol....no problem.. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need a figure to compare those `likes` with, in order to get accurate percentage.....eg How many likes constitutes 100%??

I would do it like this...

```
if($row['likes'] > 0) { 

 $likes = intval($row['likes']);
 $total = 20;  //ex....whatever number constitutes 100%;
 $width = (($likes / $total)*100)."%"; 
 ?>

//So if in this case you have 5 likes,   (5/20)*100 = 25
//$width would be set to 25%

 <div class="meter animate" align="left">
<span style="width: '<?echo $width;?>'"><span><?echo $row['likes'];?> likes </span></span>
 </div>

 <?}?>
```

Comment: I think the percentage should be logarithmic, so that it asymptotically approaches 100%

Comment: Hey KyleK got a question. Is it possible to check/echo when 100% is reached? :)

Comment: I mean like. Yes it does but i want to make a code that's like. at the time it reached 10points/100% it sends a echo. Like if width=100%{ echo:you reach 10 points! }. And i also wounder if you know how to make a max %? so it cant reach higher width then 100%?

Comment: I fixed the width problem. i just used max-width:100%;

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is incorrect:

```
if ($row['likes'] > 0) {

} elseif ($row['likes'] > 1) {
    // This will never be entered
}
```

That is because the first condition completely encloses the alternative condition.  *ie* if the number is NOT greater than zero then it is certainly not greater than 1.

It's not clear that you need the branching at all.  What's wrong with this:

```
<div class="meter animate" align="left">
    <span style="width: <?php some_width_calculation_here() ?>%"><span>
       <?php print($row['likes'] . ($row['likes'] == 1 ? "like" : "likes")); ?>
    </span></span>
</div>
```